# Train our own classifier

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Now I am training my own classifier.So for that I am using traincascade.But when I am giving this command 'opencv_traincascade -data facedet -vec vecfile.vec -bg negative.txt -npos 2650 -nneg 581 -nstages 20 -w 20 -h 20' it shows error like this.

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: facedet
vecFileName: vecfile.vec
bgFileName: negative.txt
numPos: 2000
numNeg: 1000
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 256
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 256
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 20
sampleHeight: 20
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   2000 : 2000
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    1000 : 1
Precalculation time: 3
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   4|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   5|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   6|   0.9955|    0.391|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Parameters can not be written, because file facedet/params.xml can not be opened.
```

What is this error.I don't understand.Any one help me to solve this.

Positive samples:

```
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images18413.jpeg 1 1 1 113 33
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images1392.jpeg 1 113 33 107 133
/home/arya/myown/Positive/face841.jpeg 1 185 93 35 73
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images866.jpeg 2 121 26 64 68 121 26 88 123
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images83.jpeg 1 102 13 107 136
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images355.jpeg 2 92 16 224 25 92 16 117 130
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images888.jpeg 1 108 29 116 71
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images2535.jpeg 1 108 29 111 129
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images18221.jpeg 1 110 34 109 124
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images1127.jpeg 1 110 34 92 104
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images18357.jpeg 1 103 27 142 133
/home/arya/myown/Positive/images889.jpeg 1 86 25 134 124
```

Negative samples:

```
./Negative/face150.jpeg
./Negative/face1051.jpeg
./Negative/Pictures174.jpeg
./Negative/Pictures160.jpeg
./Negative/Pictures34.jpeg
./Negative/face130.jpeg
./Negative/face1.jpeg
./Negative/Pictures319.jpeg
./Negative/face1120.jpeg
./Negative/Pictures317.jpeg
./Negative/face1077.jpeg
./Negative/Pictures93.jpeg
./Negative/Pictures145.jpeg
./Negative/face1094.jpeg
./Negative/Pictures7.jpeg
```

Comment: Make sure you are allowed to write to the directory "facedet". The error is basically saying that it cannot open the file "params.xml" in the directory "facedet". Check your permission to write to this directory using "ls -lah facedet" if you are on a "*nix" based operating system.

Comment: k.Now it's working.am doing this for face detection.So here I am giving 20 stages.After 19th stage I got an XML file.But using that XML file it can't detect the face.I gave all necessary information.

Comment: Perhaps show some of the positive and negative samples you are giving to the classifier.

Comment: Try with the trained set's positive samples. If it can not detect even that samples, than you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I put some of my positive and negative samples

Answer (score 8):

Please be sure that you have already created the folder "facedet" before training your classifier as it does not create it by itself.
It needs this folder to create "params.xml" file in inside it.

Comment: or in my case "classifiers". Check the cascadeDirName parameter emitted to console